# Filter chain questions

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following configuration in my Spring application for filter chain:

```java
@Configuration
protected static class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            
        http
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/createuser", "/index.html", "/", "/home", "/login", "/*.css", "/*.js", "/favico.ico").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I don't undrestand how it works, and i'd like to add other security constraints, for example match the path `/api/admin/*` and require the role `ADMIN` for those requests. How could I do?

I've seen the method `hasRole(String role)` but I don't understand how to use it in my case?